# What to do if the wall has too many repairs?

Tags: walls, drill, hole, hole-repair

Joint compound fixes the look of the wall, but it is not hard enough to hold another hole, correct?

Underneath the compound the support is gone (*concrete, wood, etc.*)

If a wall already had too many repairs (*compound filling holes*) and I drill one more that is right by a hidden former hole, what to do? This won't be secure enough to hold items to the wall.

**So the main question is:** A wall that has had too many repairs, what to do since it seems unreliable to hold new fixtures?

Can this actually  lead to damages in the structures, if two/three owners along the years drill too many holes?

Is there a code, standard for it? Because people simply go and put joint compound to visually hide the hole. But the hole in the underlying structure is still there.

Comment: Remove and replace drywall

Comment: What Kris says. Drywall is cheap. Un-skin the wall, level it and put it back new. Solved.   **Further, if there's a particular location that "everyone" wants to attach stuff, emplace some structure there** behind the drywall, such as a 2x12 laid flat, or a 1" thick sheet of plywood, tied into the framing of course.

Comment: What kind of wall are we talking about? Is this drywall over wood/steel studs? Is it a concrete/brick wall? Is it plaster & lathe over studs? How to repair it is going to depend entirely on the wall's construction.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question you just want to know if many patched holes compromise the structural integrity of the wall.

No the structure would not be compromised by many holes.

The wall itself may not have the integrity to hold photos or things hung on it but the wall is not going to fall over.

It is theoretically possible that if there were many holes very near each other and if someone pushed on that spot that it could give way resulting in a large hole, but the structure of the wall would still not be compromised.

> Underneath the compound the support is gone (concrete, wood, etc.)

Drilling many holes anywhere in drywall does not mean the "supports"  holding it are gone, or compromised.

***If your question is about trying to hang things where there are many holes then you need to EDIT your question to be clear on that point.***

Answer (score 1):

You can add new drywall to the existing wall. I've been involved with this a few times where people just re-drywalled the whole place. They didn't remove the old drywall, they just doubled up. It improved the sound barrier between rooms and gave them new walls to work with. I was there to bring out the switches, outlets and light fixtures with box extenders.

Comment: That causes so many niggly problems I don't recommend it except as a last resort. Electrical, door and window jambs, base trim, taping against the ceiling....

Comment: @isherwood  "niggly"?  I haven't heard that word in 60 years..lol   The contractor who did these jobs i referring to, all in Grand Rapids, did an excellent job covering up the niggly problems. It wouldn't work in all cases. Stay safe up there.